# Describe in detail a first order system of ring theory

Tags: logic

**"Describe in detail a first order system of ring theory, i.e. list the alphabet of symbols for an appropriate first order language, and write down a set of axioms and axiom schemes. Describe a model of this system which is not a ring."**

This is question  11 from Chapter 5.3 of "Logic for Mathematicians" by A. Hamilton.

I'm not sure how to write out my answer to this question. I know the definition of a ring is as follows:

"A ring is a non-empty set R equipped with two binary operations called
addition (+) and multiplication (×), satisfying the following properties:

A1 Addition is associative.
(r + s) + t = r + (s + t) for all r, s,t ∈ R.

A2 Addition is commutative. r + s = s + r for all r, s ∈ R.

A3 R contains an identity element for addition, denoted by $0_R$ and called the zero element
of R.

$r + 0_R = 0_R + r = r$ for all $r ∈ R.$

A4 Every element of R has an inverse with respect to addition. (The additive inverse of r is often denoted by −r).

For all r ∈ R, ∃ − r ∈ R for which r + (−r) = $0_R$.

M1 Multiplication is associative.
(r × s) × t = r × (s × t) for all r, s,t ∈ R.

D1 r × (s + t) = (r × s) + (r × t) for all r, s,t ∈ R.

D2 (r + s) × t = (r × t) + (s × t) for all r, s,t ∈ R.

-Distributive laws for multiplication over addition."

However I'm not sure what to do with this information. Could someone please guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*

See **5.3 The theory of groups**, page 108 :

> describe an appropriate first order language $\mathcal L_R$ : the alphabet [with the proper individual constants and function symbols, in addition to the logical ones]
>
> define $\mathcal R$ to be the extension of the *predicate calculus with equality* writing suitable proper axioms [associativity, commutativity, etc.].

---

If you have to be "fully formal", like the example of Group theory, we nedd the symbol $a_1$ for the *identity element* for addition and two function symbols : $f_1^2$ for *addition* and $f_2^2$ for *multiplication*.

Thus, your axiom A.1 will be :

> $f_1^2(f_1^2(x_1, x_2), x_3) = f_1^2(x_1,f_1^2(x_2, x_3))$.

Comment: Great, thanks for that. Could you please explain to me why we write $f^2_1$ for addition and $f^2_2$ for multiplication? Are there symbols for other functions such as power?

Comment: Also who is the author of The Theory of Groups?

Comment: @DanielleTownsend - it is only a possinility; we need two binary function letetrs, and thus we decide to use the first two in the listing. The decision to use the first for *sum* and the second for *multiplication* or viceversa is totally immaterial. And yes, we can use the third one for $x^y$.